# Product price changed while creating order

Tags: microservices, domain-driven-design

What is the DDD way of handling the following scenario:

1. user enters `Order Create` screen and starts creatingnew `Order` with `OrderItems`
2. user chooses `ProductX` from products catalog and adds quantity
3. `OrderItem` for `ProductX` is created on `Order` and user goes on adding another product
4. in the meantime, before `Order` is saved, admin changes price for ProductX

Assuming `Product` and `Order`/`OrderItem` are separate aggregates, potentially even separate bounded contexts, how is this handled?

I can think of several options:

1. optimistic concurrency combined with db transactions, but then if we broaden the question to microservices where each microservice has its own db - what then?
2. joining everything into one giant AR but that doesn’t seem right.
3. introduce a business rule that no product prices are updated during the point of sales working hours but that is often not possible (time triggered discounts, e.g.)

What is the proper DDD/microservices way of solving this?

Answer (score 3):

> What is the proper DDD/microservices way of solving this?

The general answer is that you make *time* an explicit part of your pricing model.  Price changes made to the product catalog have an effective date, which means that you can, by modeling time in the order, have complete agreement on what price the shopper saw at the time of the order.

This might introduce the concept of a *QuotedPrice* as something separate from the Catalog price, where the quote is a promise to hold a price for some amount of time.

To address this sort of problem in general, here are three important papers to review:

- Memories, Guesses, and Apologies -- [Pat Helland, 2007](https://web.archive.org/web/20100722052618/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pathelland/archive/2007/05/15/memories-guesses-and-apologies.aspx)
- Data on the Outside vs Data on the Inside -- [Pat Helland, 2005](https://blog.acolyer.org/2016/09/13/data-on-the-outside-versus-data-on-the-inside/)
- Race Conditions Don't Exist -- [Udi Dahan, 2010](https://udidahan.com/2010/08/31/race-conditions-dont-exist/)

Comment: could you please describe this modeling with time in a few sentences? i’ve read articles you’ve suggested but to be honest, it didn’t give me concrete answer to my question/dilemma. i particular, there are 2 problems: first is that price user see is the actual price and the other is that order is being saved with latest price correctly.

Comment: could you please show a small example or description what do you mean by making time explicit part of the domain model? thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think one way to solve this through is Events. As you said, `Product` and `Order` can are very least separate aggregates, I would keep them loosely coupled. Putting them into one single aggregate root would against Open/Close and Single Responsibility Principle.

If a `Product` changes it can raise a `ProductChanged` event and likewise of an `Order`.

Depending on whether these Domain-Objects are within the same service or different service you can create a Domain-Event or an Integration event. Read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/domain-events-design-implementation).

From the above link:

> A domain event is, something that happened in the domain that you want other parts of the same domain (in-process) to be aware of. The notified parts usually react somehow to the events.

I think this fits perfectly to your scenario.